# Owlrady2 Load imported onotologies from file not from url

Tags: python, owl, ontology, semantics, owlready

I'm trying to load an ontology that imports some other ontologies. These other ontologies are located on my machine and not on the web. If I try my_ontology.load() it tries to load these other ontologies from their URI. But that fails.
How can I tell owlready2 where these ontologies are located?

```
The traceback looks like this:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~Software/PyOntologyChecker/app.py", line 12, in <module>
    covid_onto = get_ontology_from_file(COVID_ONTOLOGY)
  File "~Software/PyOntologyChecker/app.py", line 8, in get_ontology_from_file
    return get_ontology("file://" + file_path).load()
  File "~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 813, in load
    imported_ontologies = [self.world.get_ontology(self._unabbreviate(abbrev_iri)).load() for abbrev_iri in self.world._get_obj_triples_sp_o(self.storid, owl_imports)]
  File "~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 813, in <listcomp>
    imported_ontologies = [self.world.get_ontology(self._unabbreviate(abbrev_iri)).load() for abbrev_iri in self.world._get_obj_triples_sp_o(self.storid, owl_imports)]
  File "~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 773, in load
    except:  raise OwlReadyOntologyParsingError("Cannot download '%s'!" % f)
owlready2.base.OwlReadyOntologyParsingError: Cannot download 'http://ontofox.hegroup.org/CHEBI_module11.owl'!
```

Comment: if the API doesn't have this feature, download the ontology as well and change the `owl:import` paths?

Comment: I guess the problem is that my link between IRI and location is located in a catalog.xml file and this API does not provide such a feature...

Comment: the catalog is not an OWL feature but something Protege specific: https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Importing_Ontologies_in_P41#Protege_and_XML_Catalogs

Comment: Also, owlready2 provides a way to change the imports: https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/onto.html#importing-other-ontologies , but I don't think during loading. But again, why can't you download the main ontology and change the import locations in the file?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a local copy of `CHEBI_module11.owl` dependence (ex. `SOME_DIR/HEBI_module11.owl`), add its location into `onto_path` (as stated in the [docs](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/onto.html#loading-an-ontology-from-owl-files)):

```
onto_path.append("SOME_DIR")
```

before doing `my_ontology.load()`. That tells Owlready2 to look for files in `SOME_DIR`. The path can be relative or absolute (like `c:/data/ontologies`).

The current Python's working directory is **not scanned** by default but can be set so with `onto_path.append(".")`.

If a required ontology is described by URI not ending with a usual filename, like `"http://rdf.webofcode.org/woc/"`, the local filename (`woc` in this case) should not have an extension.